# restricted OTA of iphone app

Tags: ios

We have a created an Appstore for internal distribution of apps in our enterprise.
We use OTA for enterprise distribution in this appstore. Here for downloading the app we use a link like below :
 Tap Here to Install the Application

Now we have a new requirement , where we want to restrict the app download for a given user to 3 times. Basically a given user cannot install a given app from the appstore for more than 3 times in 6 months. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What do you refer to with OTA? And this is an app store you built yourself? So you implemented user management I assume? (you'd have to as Apple allows distribution to employees of your enterprise if you're an enterprise iOS developer). So can't you just save each time a user accesses the app in a database?